# PHP MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE from CSV File Upload

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to learn how to upload new records to MySQL table but seem to be failing so far. My attempt:

```
$uploaded = $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"];
`$try = mysqli_query($connect,"LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE $uploaded INTO TABLE allrecords");`
```

I get an error. It's expected though as the code is a mess. I tried searching in Google but all seem to offer only inserting each records one by one to the database. I used a  tag to select the Excel CSV file (exported from Excel) then on the receiving PHP file I use this query.

I use LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE because I want to upload new records to the database but not include records who's primary key already exist in the database. Also I'm not sure how to do LOAD DATA INFILE and match each fields. Do I need to rename each column names/headers in Excel CSV to match the field names in database?

Comment: Post your error messages or stack trace.

Comment: I think what he wants to do @TimBiegeleisen is to get those surrounding single quotes around the `'/full/path/to/filename'`, and to ironically not `ignore 1 lines`, and tweak line 1 to be perfect

Comment: @Drew Post this as an answer.  And the OP should have included error output.  Then I would not have to take wild guesses.

Comment: ah, resurrect yours, don't know if I have the strength :>

Comment: like I was doing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32263290/1816093) though it was for export not import, those single quotes (or the lack thereof) can screwup everything

Comment: yeah guys I just confirmed it over there on that Answer. If I don't do the single quotes I get error 1064. Put em back it, I get my export. OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE are connected by the hip with syntax finickiness and share almost everything in common

Comment: I think he also needs `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` since he's using an Excel exported CSV file.  Comma is not the default separator.

Comment: I only trapped it with `if(!$try) echo` which gives out the error message but if I don't trap it with that there's no error at all and nothing is uploaded to the database

Answer (score 1):

As @drew wisely mentioned in his comments above, you are missing single quotes around the file name in your `LOAD DATA` statement, which can mess things up.  You *may* also be missing a few other things which would prevent it from working.

Try using this PHP code instead:

```
$uploaded = $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"];
`$try = mysqli_query($connect,"LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE '$uploaded' INTO TABLE allrecords FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\r\n'");`
```

Here is that `LOAD DATA` command as separate (readable) query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE '$uploaded'
INTO TABLE allrecords
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\r\n'
```

Note *carefully* that the double quote in `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` has to be *escaped* so PHP doesn't choke.

And as another aside comment, `LOAD DATA` is fairly primitive with regard to what it can do handling data.  It is intended as a workhorse to bring in raw data to MySQL.  For complex filtering and manipulations of your raw data, you are probably better off doing the work in MySQL proper.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Drew, I will try this now and get back to you :)

Comment: what did you mean better off doing the work in MySQL proper? Did you mean INSERT each rows one by one in a loop? I was going to do that first but I thought it would make the process run very slow?

Comment: I mean that if you have complex rules for selectively retaining/excluding certain records, you are better off just reading in everything in one shot and then cleaning up the table inside MySQL where you have a wealth of tools to help you do that.

Comment: Using:
`$try = mysqli_query($connect,"LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE '$uploaded' INTO TABLE allrecords FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\r\n'");`

I get error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' LINES TERMINATED BY '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/hidden/public_html/subfolder/loader.php on line 41`

Comment: I forgot to escape the double quotes.  Check my updated answer.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I still get a captured error from `if(!$try) echo` but removing `if(!$try) echo` doesn't reveal the true error. Am I missing something else? What code do I use to reveal the true error so I can send it here?

Comment: Let's try simplifying: `mysqli_query($connect,"LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE '$uploaded' INTO TABLE allrecords FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','");`

Comment: Still the same. Do I really need to use `INTO TABLE allrecords` or should it be just `INTO allrecords`? I even tried removing `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` and still getting the error

Comment: You need `INTO TABLE`.